# Passing parameter for c# selenium test BDD

Tags: c#, selenium, bdd, specflow

I have written a specflow scenario.

```
Given Inventory interface is generated  
And I Loaded LifeCycle Measurement in integration domain for <lifecyclestatus>
When Inventory batch is executed
Then Transfer out measure should be generated <lifecyclestatus>
Examples: 
| Lifecyclestatus |
| Prenew          |
| New             |
| Current         |
| Clearance       |
| Old             |
```

How can i pass a parameter in my c# code so it runs all of the different status in the table?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameter by creating the step definition method as given below.

```
    [And(@"I Loaded LifeCycle Measurement in integration domain for (.*)")]
    public void AndILoadedLifeCycleMeasurementInIntegrationDomainFor(string lifecycleStatus)
    {
       //your code goes here
    }

    [Then(@"Transfer out measure should be generated (.*)")]
    public void ThenTransferOutMeasureShouldBeGenerated(string lifecycleStatus)
    {
       //your code goes here
    }
```

Comment: Yes correct. Once i generate the step definition i can see all the examples at the bottom after the GVT. Will the parameters be passed through here?

Comment: Yes it will be passed